# Hide "VPN Active" persisting notification in Android 12

Tags: vpn, android-12

I use VPN 24*7. Earlier I used to be able to hide "VPN active" notification but since I upgraded to Android 12, the option is not there anymore.

What should I do to hide the notification?

Comment: Which notification did you mean? I just checked on Pixel 3a, Android 12, and there's no "VPN active" notification. Is it on the quick setting panel ("This device is connected to "[name of the VPN app]"), or on the notification panel which is usually a notification by the app? Could you mention the device model and/or post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can tap & hold to use the notification controls by turning off notifications from certain apps, or tap the settings button for advanced options.

[image: Notification control [12.1]]

Tip: You can also hide the VPN icon on the status bar with third-party apps with advanced adb tool.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on developer options and switch on demo mode :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't remove it anymore in android 12.
Some models let you remove the notification over a system menu.

On my oppo there is a hack:
Download a PDF on edge (maybe it works also with chrome).
Then press on "remove all notifications"
This removes it until the next start.

Answer (score 0):

The OP seems to ask about VPN-app's own custom-notification,
I mean, because newer Android versions no longer show such notification.

You can only get rid of said custom-notification,
by removing notification permission of said app.

Another option would be asking their developers (or customer support) for such feature.

It's little hard, but said developers can remove notification,
by starting their `VpnService` in a separate process, like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38496939/8740349